# Create two network isolated from each other.( LAN to WAN ). How can I prevent the network from router 2 to be able to ping router 1?

Tags: router, home-networking

[network map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxr7N.png)

1- I setup the DHCP range on the router 1 like in the picture and then i setup the DHCP range also on the router 2. What I did is setup the ip adress like this: 192.168.2.61 then restart the router and the adress became like in the picture. Why is that ?

2- Is this setup is enough to isolate the smart devices from reaching the devices connected to the router 2 ? I can access the router 1 from the router 2 network. But I can't ping the router 2 from router 1. So thats why I think the network are isolated. Am I right ?

The connection is LAN ( router 1 ) to WAN ( router 2 )

Answer (score 0):

(1) You set up the WAN (or LAN) address of router 2 to 192.168.2.61.  In order for the LAN side or Router 2 to have a 10.x.x.x. address, you would have set it up this way.

(2) The isolation done this way is enough for household guest devices. It does not prevent hackers but I assume your guests are not hackers.

(2a) It is normal to be able to ping. You should be able to ping 192.168.2.61 on router two. But it will not see farther than that.

I use the above approach in volunteer organizations to prevent random snooping on the main network and it works well. Guests are simply not interested (and most not capable) of hacking in.